# How to set spring context in a Jersey test with external provider

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I want to run a Jersey Test with external provider

```
[group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers', name: 'jersey-test-framework-provider-external' , version: '2.17']
```

Now i have a running server on which when launched had used a spring application context to connect to a database(say main database)
Now i want to run my JerseyTest using external provider to run my tests on this server but use another spring context to use a test database.Is this possible?
Here is what i attempted

```
  public class MyTest extends JerseyTest {
//Already running server where application is deployed
      private static final String MY_TEST_URL = "http://localhost:8080/somepath";

      private static class MyTestContainer extends ExternalTestContainerFactory {
        private  DeploymentContext customContext;
        public MyTestContainer(DeploymentContext configureDeployment) {
          this.customContext=configureDeployment;
        }

        @Override
        public TestContainer create(URI baseUri, DeploymentContext context)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
          try {
            baseUri = new URI(MY_TEST_URL);
          } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
          return super.create(baseUri, customContext);
        }
      }

        @Override
      protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
         ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(MyRestResource.class);
         config.packages("com.myapp.restful");
         ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("MyTest-applicationContext.xml");
         config.property("contextConfig", context);
         DeploymentContext custom=DeploymentContext.builder(config).build();
         return custom; //return a deployment context with different spring context
         };
      private  final ExternalTestContainerFactory testContainer = new MyTestContainer(this.configureDeployment());

       @Override
      public TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
       return testContainer;
     }


      @Test
      public void testCreateResouce(){

        target(path).request().post(entity); //post some entity to the server
      }

    }
```

But since the already running server used a spring configuration which uses the "main database" this creates the entity in "main database".All the configuration done in test is ignored?
If nothing is already deployed on the server then it gives 404 response.
How does the configuration from the test work?